# Using both named instance and port in mssql npm module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sql-server, database

I am trying to connect to a database which has both a named instance and port defined

I am using a React/Node app with the server using mssql npm module to connect

Node module works well when connecting to dbs which only have server ip and I can connect to this db with named instance + port using SSMS

`{  server: 'servername.com/namedinstance01', options: { port: 01234 }`

I notice in the docs it suggests the two are incompatible:
'port - Port to connect to (default: 1433). Don't set when connecting to named instance.'

Has anyone come across this? Is db port and named instance by design supposed to be mutually exclusive? I don't administrate this db so I have no control over this

Would expect to connect but getting a generic connection error

Comment: Logically you only need to specify one or the other. A named instance runs on a specific port. The SQL browser service should map the named instance to a port and connect on that port. In the example you've given above, it's possible that `namedinstance01` is tunning on port `01234`. Or it could just be that when both are specified, one overrides the other.

Comment: Me, personally, I disagree with the docs. If you know which port an instance is listening on then use that port in the connection properties. Using instance names adds a layer of unreliability because the client first has to make an SSRP (SQL Server Resolution Protocol) query to the SQL Browser service via udp/1434, which resolves the instance name to the port that it's listening on, then the client makes the connection to the resolved port. Your connection problem is probably due to using forward slashes - by convention the server address is delimited from the instance name by a backslash.

Comment: Aside... in Javascript starting a number with `0` signifies that it is in octal notation. `01234` octal would be `668` decimal.

Comment: Thank you all, in the end the port was mapped to the instance name. So specifying server and then port in the config works.